# Combining adjoining SequenceMatcher matches

Tags: python, string, sequence

Is there an option or method for difflib.SequenceMatcher to combine adjoining Matches?

Consider this pair:

```
str_a = "Attempt to invoke virtual method XXX.XXX on a null object reference"

str_b = "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{YYY/YYY.YYYActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void ZZZ.ZZZ(ZZZ.ZZZ.WWW.product.BaseActivity)' on a null object reference"
```

Excuse the non-minimal examples but the matches returned seem sensitive to even small deletions.

```
[((i,j,n),str_a[i:i+n],str_b[j:j+n]) for i,j,n in difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,str_a,str_b).get_matching_blocks()]
```

Then

```
[((0, 50, 1), 'A', 'A'),
 ((1, 94, 17), 'ttempt to invoke ', 'ttempt to invoke '),
 ((22, 158, 1), 'u', 'u'),
 ((40, 176, 27), ' on a null object reference', ' on a null object reference'),
 ((67, 203, 0), '', '')]
```

But why are  'A' and 'ttempt to invoke' returned as 2 separate matches since they are adjoining? Is there a method to join them internally?

Comment: There are three As in the second string. It decided to match the A at the start of the first string with the first A and not the second.

Comment: @DanD, ok but that doesn't answer the q why is it matching just the A and not the longer string Attempt?